# Digitally signed e-mail with attachment

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, email, email-attachments

I have a mailer script which sends a single digitally signed e-mail. Now I have to attach file(s) to the mails. My issues:

1. If there is no attachment, the mail is OK and digitally signed. This is OK.
2. If there is any attachment, the mailbody is missing and it's not signed, however it sends the files properly. Why this happens?

`mailer(to, from, from_name, relay, subject, body, attachment_list);`

```
private void mailer(string toaddress, string fromaddress, string fromaddress_disp, string relays, string mailsubject, string bodytext, List<string> att)
{
    string certname = "";

    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromaddress, fromaddress_disp);
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(toaddress);
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

    //this is the attachment part added
    if (att.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < att.Count; i++)
            {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(att[i].ToString());
                message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
        }
    //this is the end of attachment part added

    message.Subject = mailsubject;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    string body = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n" + bodytext;
    byte[] messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
    ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(messageData);

    SignedCms Cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(messageData));
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;
    X509Certificate2 cert = null;
    foreach (X509Certificate2 c in certCollection)
    {
        if ((c.Subject.Contains("myEmailAddress")) && (c.FriendlyName.Contains("CompanyEmailDigSig")))
        {
            cert = c;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (cert != null)
    {
            csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Valid certificate was not found");
    }

    CmsSigner Signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, cert);
    Cms.ComputeSignature(Signer);
    byte[] SignedBytes = Cms.Encode();
    MemoryStream signedStream = new MemoryStream(SignedBytes);
    AlternateView signedView = new AlternateView(signedStream, "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name=sig.p7m");
    message.AlternateViews.Add(signedView);
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(relays);
    store.Close();

    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //exception
    }
}
```

The problem will be that it's signing the body only:

```
byte[] messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(messageData);
SignedCms Cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(messageData));
```

How to sign the entire mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally solve this issue with EASendMail:

http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/dev/csharp.asp

This code signs the whole e-mail messeage along with any attachment and/or embedded image. It's also very easy to use.

Comment: The link is no longer available.